# SQL Check if one of record is not exists with join other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried and searched for the solution but found anything.
I want to make a SQL Code which Check if one of a records is not existing in another table.

SQL Tables:

```
Table name: ads
╔═══════╦═════════╗
║ ad_id ║ user_id ║
╠═══════╬═════════╣
║  1    ║ Jeff    ║
║  2    ║ Jeff    ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩

Second Table name: premium
╔═══════╦═════════╗
║ ad_id ║ user_id ║
╠═══════╬═════════╣
║  1    ║ Jeff    ║
```

I want to Check the table Ads if the user_id = Jeff has not an record in table Premium. Barely it should show me in that case ad_id = 2

What I have tried is:

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
INNER JOIN premium ON premium.ad_id = ads.id 
WHERE premium.user_id = 'Jeff'
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from ads a
where not exists (select 1
                  from premium p
                  where p.ad_id = a.ad_id and p.user_id = a.user_id
                 );
```

This is almost a direct translation of your problem statement.  In addition, with an index on `premium(ad_id, user_id)` it should also have very good performance characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

You may use correlated subquery with `NOT IN`

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM ads a 
 WHERE a.ad_id NOT IN
( SELECT p.ad_id FROM premium p WHERE p.user_id = a.user_id and p.user_id = 'Jeff' );
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edae0d/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.`ad_id` as ad_id, p.`user_id` as user_id
FROM `premium` p 
INNER JOIN `ads` a ON a.`user_id` = p.`user_id`
WHERE p.`user_id` = 'Jeff'
GROUP BY p.`user_id`
HAVING a.`ad_id` = MIN(a.`ad_id`)
```

`MIN(a.ad_id)` you are must replace with condition what record you are want to select from table `ads`

And so on. If you are want records `Check if one of a records is not existing in another table` so

```
SELECT COUNT(a.`ad_id`) as cnt
FROM `premium` p 
INNER JOIN `ads` a ON a.`user_id` = p.`user_id`
WHERE p.`user_id` = 'Jeff'
GROUP BY p.`user_id`
HAVING a.`ad_id` <> MIN(a.`ad_id`)
```

So, if `cnt > 0` its mean what records are exists!

If you are have a strong relation within an `p.ad_id === a.ad_id` :

```
SELECT COUNT(a.`ad_id`) as cnt
FROM `premium` p 
INNER JOIN `ads` a ON a.`user_id` = p.`user_id`
WHERE p.`user_id` = 'Jeff' AND a.`ad_id` <> p.`ad_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this:

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
LEFT OUTER JOIN premium ON premium.ad_id = ads.id 
WHERE ads.user_id = 'Jeff' AND premium.ad_id IS NULL
```